# How to dynamically get column names from TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I have tried

```
let modelClass = (await import('@models/' + modelName + '.ts'))[modelName];
let keys = Object.keys(modelClass);//no column names included, only custom helper vars i.e. NoteColumnVarcharLength
let keys = Object.keys(new modelClass());//nothing at all in this model
```

Is there a helper function in the library to automatically get them all?

Comment: I think it might help: connection.getMetadata(MyEntity);
Source:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1764

Comment: I like that solution at the bottom of your link, put that in an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As proposed in the issue on repository of that library ([link](http://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1764)) can be solved by using

```
connection.getMetadata("User").columns
```

Comment: Also `getConnection().getMetadata(Organization).ownColumns.map(column => column.propertyName)`

Comment: For people who set an alias in their entity via `@Column({name: 'foo'})`, check for `column.databaseName` instead. `column.propertyName` will go off the entity instead of the actual name in the database.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer looks incomplete, and many questions appeared in my head when I tried to apply the answer. So I write my own to cover the question well.

We must first retrieve [EntityMetadata](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_entitymetadata_.entitymetadata.html) to get column names. We can retrieve **EntityMetadata** from [Connection](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_connection_connection_.connection.html), which we can get in any comfortable way.

```
import { getConnection, getManager } from 'typeorm';

const connection1 = getConnection();
const connection2 = getManager().connection;
```

Next, we need to retrieve entity metadata.

We can do it via

```
const metadata = connection.getMetadata(modelClass);
```

Inside entity metadata you can use several options to find a column. If you need to look for all columns, you need to use [`columns`](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_entitymetadata_.entitymetadata.html#columns). If you are going to look only over user-defined columns, you can use [`ownColumns`](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_entitymetadata_.entitymetadata.html#owncolumns).

These properties contain arrays with [`ColumnMetadata`](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_columnmetadata_.columnmetadata.html).

If you just need a list of user-defined columns, you can just return mapped values of [`propertyName`](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_columnmetadata_.columnmetadata.html#propertyname).

```
const columns = metadata.columns.map((column) => column.propertyName);
```

In my case, I needed to find the database column name by a property name.

I used a `find()` method for my case.

```
const column = metadata.ownColumns.find((column) => column.propertyName === propertyName);
```

If I need to find several columns I would create a map between [`propertyName`](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_columnmetadata_.columnmetadata.html#propertyname) and [`databaseName`](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_columnmetadata_.columnmetadata.html#databasename);

```
const columnMap = Object.fromEntries(
  metadata.ownColumns((column) => ([column.propertyName, column.databaseName]))
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the embedded entity columns? For example, if my "user" table has a relationship with the "photo" table, can I access the columns of the "photo" entity from the user entity's metadata?

Comment: @GisCat, I already left that project, where we were using TypeORM, so I can't answer this question.

Most possibly there might be something useful inside `column.relationMetadata.inverseRelationMetadata` https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_metadata_relationmetadata_.relationmetadata#inverseentitymetadata, but it is just a suggestion.

Feel free to share your investigations if you find something useful. Or maybe someone else will be able to respond to your question.

Comment: I find a way to get it, Thank you for the help ! I used this to retrieve the columns `connection.getMetadata(User).relations.map((relation) => relation.inverseEntityMetadata.propertiesMap);`